# bitnami gitlab 7.14.3-0 error "your change could not be committed"

Tags: gitlab, bitnami

os: ubuntu 12.04_x64
bitnami gitlab :7.14.3-0

I tried to edit the readme file for a repository on gitlab web page, it returned me an error "your change could not be committed...".
I have tried to remove native ruby,but it didn't work for me.
here are some log information:

githost.log

```
November 15, 2015 14:59 -> ERROR -> Command failed [128]: /opt/gitlab-7.14.3-0/git/bin/git --git-dir=/opt/gitlab-7.14.3-0/apps/gitlab/gitlab-satellites/wang/test/.git --work-tree=/opt/gitlab-7.14.3-0/apps/gitlab/gitlab-satellites/wang/test push origin master:master
git: '/opt/gitlab-7.14.3-0/apps/gitlab/repositories/wang/test.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Hope to get some help from you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Developer here,

This issue is fixed in the gitlab 8.1.4 version.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, but there is also problems in bitnami gitlab 8.1.4, I can not clone or push via http, however ssh is ok.

Comment: You are right. We are working on fixing the issue in the new revision. 

Regards.